# Где хранить логин/пароль на устройстве?

Tags: android, криптография

Какой есть способ лучше SharedPreferences, чтобы хранить логин/пароль или авторизационный токен? Хочется их хоть немного защитить от несанкционированного доступа.

Comment: Если по простому, то хранить можно и в преференсах и в БД и еще где то.. главное зашифровать. В Java есть свой пакет [`javax.cripto`](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/package-summary.html), в Android своя система [`Android Keystore`](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html)/ еще [вот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/308901/177345)

Answer (score 5):

1. Пароль нельзя хранить
2. Если вы решили все таки хранить пароль см. п.1
3. Если совсем уж сильно хочется читайте ниже:

Хранить надо:

```
String hashString=hash(password+salt);
```

где:

`salt` случайная строка сгененированная криптостойким ГСЧ

`hash()` - [криптостойкий хэш алгоритм](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) - лучше всего итеративный что-то типа 100k итераций

Хранить надо `hashString` и `salt`

Comment: Не, пароль не в приложение, пароль на сервер. Старое наследие. Токенов нет. Пользователь его один раз укажет, но дальше надо запомнить, потому что спрашивать каждый раз - не вариант вообще. Я вспомнил, мы в похожем случае сделали пин и симметричный алгоритм, всяко лучше, чем ничего. Надо будет еще на работу со сканером отпечатков посмотреть, пока про нее ничего не знаю.

Comment: Твой ответ, на который pavlofff указал, мне больше в тему.

Comment: В указанном контексте вариант в старом ответе более работоспособен - это да. Только хранить надо не пароль - а ключ/токен