# Как сохранить пароль при регистрации, после выхода приложения

Tags: android

Здравствуйте
Первое прошу не ставьте минусы, мы же новички и многое не понимаем
а теперь вопрос 
Есть программа, где есть одно activity для регистрации, и одно activity для логина. 
Программа должен работать так, что при первом открытий открывался activity регистрации. После этого пользователь создает пароль, нажимает регистрация и попадает на activity логина, там тоже вводит пароль, и если правильно, попадает на следующее activity, ну где его страница. 
В программе что-то не то, когда при первом открытий создает пароль и делает вход, то все работает, но после закрытий приложения, если открыть следующий раз, то открывается окно логина(так и должно быть), просто когда ввожу пароль, который создал, не работает.
ВОПРОС. Как делать, чтобы после закрытий приложения, пароль сохранялся, и при входе если пароль, который вводили, работает, то делать вход.

вот код
Activity for Registration

```
private Button button0, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, buttondel, buttonreg;
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main2 );
    button1 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button1 );
    button2 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button2 );
    button3 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button3 );
    button4 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button4 );
    button5 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button5 );
    button6 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button6 );
    button7 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button7 );
    button8 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button8 );
    button9 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button9 );
    button0 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button0 );
    buttondel = (Button) findViewById( R.id.buttondel );
    buttonreg = (Button) findViewById( R.id.buttonreg );
    textView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.text );

    button1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( textView.getText() + "1" );
        }
    } );
    button2.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( textView.getText() + "2" );
        }
    } );
    button3.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( textView.getText() + "3" );
        }
    } );
    button4.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( textView.getText() + "4" );
        }
    } );
    button5.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( textView.getText() + "5" );
        }
    } );
    button6.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( textView.getText() + "6" );
        }
    } );
    button7.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( textView.getText() + "7" );
        }
    } );
    button8.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( textView.getText() + "8" );
        }
    } );
    button9.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( textView.getText() + "9" );
        }
    } );
    button0.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( textView.getText() + "0" );
        }
    } );
    buttondel.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( "" );
        }
    } );
    buttonreg.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (!(textView.getText().equals( "" ))) {
                Intent intent = new Intent( Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class );
                String s = textView.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra( "text", s );
                startActivity( intent );
            } else {
                textView.setText( "" );
            }
        }
    } );
}
```

}

Activity for Login

```
private Button button0, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, buttondel, buttonlog;
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences( "Preference", MODE_PRIVATE ).
            getBoolean( "Is first run", true );
    if (isFirstRun) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class );
        startActivity( intent );
        getSharedPreferences( "Preference", MODE_PRIVATE ).edit().putBoolean( "Is first run", false ).commit();
    }

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String s = intent.getStringExtra( "text" );
    button1 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button1 );
    button2 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button2 );
    button3 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button3 );
    button4 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button4 );
    button5 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button5 );
    button6 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button6 );
    button7 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button7 );
    button8 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button8 );
    button9 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button9 );
    button0 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button0 );
    buttondel = (Button) findViewById( R.id.buttondel );
    buttonlog = (Button) findViewById( R.id.buttonlog );
    textView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.text );

    button1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( textView.getText() + "1" );
        }
    } );
    button2.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( textView.getText() + "2" );
        }
    } );
    button3.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( textView.getText() + "3" );
        }
    } );
    button4.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( textView.getText() + "4" );
        }
    } );
    button5.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( textView.getText() + "5" );
        }
    } );
    button6.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( textView.getText() + "6" );
        }
    } );
    button7.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( textView.getText() + "7" );
        }
    } );
    button8.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( textView.getText() + "8" );
        }
    } );
    button9.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( textView.getText() + "9" );
        }
    } );
    button0.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( textView.getText() + "0" );
        }
    } );
    buttondel.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText( "" );
        }
    });
    buttonlog.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (textView.getText().equals(  s )) {
                Intent intent =  new Intent( MainActivity.this, Main3Activity.class );
                startActivity( intent );
               } 

            else textView.setText( "" );
        }
    } );
}
```

}

Comment: Есть такой виджет - `KeyboardView`, с помощью него можно сделать собственную [полноценную клавиатуру любого вида](https://inducesmile.com/android/how-to-create-an-android-custom-keyboard-application/)

Comment: Уже был вопрос [по хранению паролей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/308901/177345) и есть ответы

Comment: @Hayk попробуйте сделать по ссылке (там реально есть ответы), потом выложите сюда, как ответ. Если он будет рабочим, мы плюсанём) Это будет Вашим стимулом.